# where is Apple documentation for TableViewCell View Modes (that appear in Interface Builder)?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, interface-builder

where is Apple documentation for TableViewCell View Modes (that appear in Interface Builder)?

I can't seem to find them - the modes include options such as:

- scale to fit
- aspect fit
- aspect fill
- redraw
- centre . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView`'s `contentMode` is what you're after. UITableViewCell just inherits this property from UIView.

[UIView - contentMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode)